# web application redesign suggestion

Tags: web-app, web, business-application

We had built a application using Ext JS web desktop. Something similar to:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/desktop/desktop.html

The application is basically a web based administration panel which has many modules(Around 20 modules). Each module is a Ext JS window and you have numerous options that you can change. The clients were using for sometime. Right now they are saying they don't quite like it. They quite liked the idea of the desktop when it was first introduced. I'm thinking that their main concern is that the application kind of looks too much like a windows application. They don't like the extjs grid etc. They had casually mentioned that they quite like the interface of basecamp PM tool.

My options are to keep the desktop as it is and redesign the windows so that they are more usable. Most windows would list a entries on the left panel and on clicking a entry the form on the right gets filled up, which can be edited and saved.

Do you guys have any suggestion to redesign the desktop app into something else. Keep in mind that this is a enterprise application used to configure some back end processes, display some realtime statistics etc.

Comment: This is currently a bit too localized to your own situation, and as such isn't going to be accurately answerable by anyone here, nor be of much use to any future visitors. It's been closed off for this reason, but if there is a more specific item you need help with rather than just a full-on redesign request then you're welcome to edit the question accordingly. However it's just not something we can really help with in any constructive way at the moment.

Comment: Enterprise apps arent' to look cool and if there's one thing you can hardly do with ExtJS app is to remove its windows-ish look. You could either redesign it from scratch using different tools (like, twitter bootstrap), or switch to a different layout within ExtJS, like Portal, or how the Feed reader or mail app looks like.